# Не получается сделать паралакс

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parallax

Доброго времени суток, учусь делать паралакс но не выходит, выбивает кучу ошибок, нуждаюсь в помощи гуру.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".header_text").css({
    "transform" : "translate(0%, " + st + "%"
  }); 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.sect_1 {
  background-image: url(../q.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header_text {
  color: #542222;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -39px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<section class="sect_1">
  <div class="header_text">Gray Studio</div>
</section>

<section></section>
```

Comment: поробуйте заюзать етот код https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js

Comment: font-family: "Arial", sans-serif двоеточие после font-family,  "transform" : "translate(0%, " + st + "%)" <=== скобка. И никаких ошибок консоль не вываливает.